# angular2, directive input OnChanges delay(debounce)?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In Angular1, I was able to add add debounce time for `ng-model`.

In Angular2, we can detect changes on all `input`. Is it possible to have some debounce time on each input change.

From the following plunker example, http://plnkr.co/edit/JKYSek?p=preview, I type "hello world", but it reacts to every single key stroke.

Is it possible to have some delay on each change without any programming?

```
import { Directive, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]',
  inputs: [`myInput`]
}) 
export class MyDirective implements OnChanges {

  ngOnChanges(changes: {[key: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    console.log('changes :'+ changes.myInput.currentValue);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular doesn't provide anything. It was discussed and there is an open issue AFAIR.

As workaround you can forward to an observable or use `Observable.fromEvent()` with `debounce`.